# Magento - getModel() and getResourceModel

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I'm developing news extension for Magento following official Guide by Magento and book "Magento PHP Developers Guide".

In the book there are registry entities, items and type - and I think this will be a good practice for the future to add maybe Categories to the News extension. For now I just have Item table that has only news items in it.

According to the book I created the folder structure and placed my files like this:

```
-Model
--Mysql4
---Item
----Collection.php
---Item.php
--Resource
----Setup.php
--Item.php
```

in the official guide there's:

```
-Model
--Resource
---Item
----Collection.php
---Item.php
--Item.php
```

1. **What is the difference between these two? Are they both EAV?**

I have setup everything (installer scripts) following the book and it worked just fine.
Now I have Controller, Block and template file and I'm trying to display the data from the database.

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <gott_news>
            <class>Gott_News_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>gott_news_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </gott_news>
        <gott_news_mysql4>
            <entities>
                <item>
                    <table>gott_news_item</table>
                </item>
            </entities>
        </gott_news_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <gott_news_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Gott_News</module>
                <class>Gott_News_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </gott_news_setup>
    </resources>
```

Following the book it retrives data from DB like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('gott_news/item')->getCollection();
```

the guide does it:

```
$newsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('gott_news/item_collection');
$newsCollection->prepareForList($this->getCurrentPage);
```

This prepareForList() function is located in the Collection.php file. I actually should end up this `prepareForList()` to pass a variable of `currentPage`

**The Problem:**
Neither works for me. It doesn't get any results from DB. and when I use `prepareForList()` it says it's non-object

In the book, there's also

```
    <resources>
        <mdg_giftregistry_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mdg_Giftregistry</module>
                <class>Mdg_Giftregistry_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </mdg_giftregistry_setup>
        <mdg_giftregistry_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </mdg_giftregistry_write>
        <mdg_giftregistry_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </mdg_giftregistry_read>
    </resources>
```

Is this needed to get data from DB?

In the `indexController.php indexAction()` I'm trying to get Data but nothing is being returned:

```
$blogpost = Mage::getModel('gott_news/item')->getCollection();
```

**What should I do to make it work???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem before and it seems that the mysql4 calling is the old fashion when ressources are the one to be used now.
I use something like that and it works just fine. I don't know if it is compatible with the versions before 1.7

```
        <models>
        <gottnews>
            <class>Gott_News_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>gottnews_resource</resourceModel>
        </gottnews>    
        <gottnews_resource>
            <class>Gott_News_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <item>
                    <table>gott_news</table>
                </item>
            </entities>
        </gottnews_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <gott_news_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Gott_News</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </gott_news_setup>
        <gottnews_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </gottnews_write>
        <gottnews_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </gottnews_read>
    </resources>
```

In the table core_ressource, you need to find the name of your module with its version. If it is not, the setup script did not run correctly and you need to check var/log/ for more info if you have logging activated in magento. if it is but you need to run again the setup, delete the line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I read something like that about Mysql4 approach and it in deed said that Mysql4 approach worked only till 1.7 version. And I also checked and it seems that this book "Magento PHP Developers Guide" is based on 1.7 that's why it works there but it doesnt in 1.9. I'll try what you wrote here. Thank you again

Comment: and I have another question: you wrote write and read permissions in xml nodes. what does it do? and why is it needed? can you explain?

Comment: I'm sorry but I never really wondered about that because it works the same without it. I believe it is needed when you have different connections type for your module.